# loading neo4j dump in docker container

Tags: docker, neo4j

I am using docker to launch multiple instances of neo4j instances for my project. 
I have a requirement that I have to load a graph dump to one of my neo4j docker container and I have to do it again an again (as the graph dump will be provided by a separate group of people).

These are my steps that I have followed in order to do the same -

```
    # docker run --publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687 \
    --volume=/home/dimension/neo4j/container3/data:/data \
    --volume=/home/dimension/neo4j/container3/logs:/logs \
    --volume=/home/dimension/neo4j/container3/conf:/conf \
    --volume=/home/dimension/neo4j/container3/plugins:/plugins \
    neo4j:3.3.3

    # docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS                                                      NAMES
eee581b2f493        neo4j:3.3.3         "/docker-entrypoint.…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 seconds               0.0.0.0:7474->7474/tcp, 7473/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7687->7687/tcp   priceless_ride
```

This brings up the container, but the database is empty. Next I tried the following to load a neo4j dump to my newly built docker container

```
# docker stop priceless_ride
priceless_ride

# cp home/dimension/neo4j/dumps/2018-09-05.dump ~/neo4j/container3/data/

# docker run --publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687 \
--volume=/home/dimension/neo4j/container3/data:/data \
--volume=/home/dimension/neo4j/container3/logs:/logs \
--volume=/home/dimension/neo4j/container3/conf:/conf \
--volume=/home/dimension/neo4j/container3/plugins:/plugins \
-i -t neo4j:3.3.3 /bin/bash
```

The above command creates a separate container and runs the container in interactive mode. Once I am inside the container I run -

```
bash-4.4# bin/neo4j-admin load --from=/data/2018-09-05.dump --database=graph.db --force
bash-4.4# exit
```

Now I execute `docker ps -a` command, I will see 2 container in the output

```
docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
073c31c75ff5        neo4j:3.3.3         "/docker-entrypoint.…"   8 seconds ago       Exited (0) 3 seconds ago                       focused_zhukovsky
eee581b2f493        neo4j:3.3.3         "/docker-entrypoint.…"   3 hours ago         Exited (0) 7 minutes ago                       priceless_ride
```

I have to remove the newly built container as it is no longer needed. by executing `docker rm focused_zhukovsky`

Every thing works fine, when I restarted my container by executing command

```
# docker start priceless_ride
```

and check the browser using `http://127.0.0.1:7474/browser/`, the container now has the loaded database form the dump.

Following the above steps for loading a graph dump is okay, but its cumbersome if I have to do it again and again. Is their a cleaner way to load neo4j dump without the need to start a separate container in interactive mode and then firing `neo4j-admin load` command.

Is it possible to start the docker container without running the neo4j inside it. If this is possible then I can go inside the container and fire the `neo4j-admin load` command as many time I want.

I am stuck at this problem from quite some time. I will deeply appreciate any help on this issue.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: I wrote a python script to automate the above process. I wasn't able to find a solution  to start the docker container without running the neo4j instance inside it.